# Using arc to create a circle in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, dynamic

I am creating a canvas dynamically and then drawing a circle.
However, as shown, the circle appears stretched and offset:

```js
var max = 50;
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id = "mazecanvas";
var size = (document.documentElement.clientWidth / 100) * max;
canvas.style.width = size + "px";
canvas.style.height = size + "px";
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.left = size / 2 + "px";
canvas.style.top = (document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2) - (size / 2) + "px";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var x, y;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function circle() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
  ctx.beginPath();
  console.log(x, y);
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  x = mousePos.x;
  y = mousePos.y;
}, false);

function draw() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < max; j++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(255 - 5.5 * i) + ',' + Math.floor(255 - 5.5 * j) + ',0)';
      ctx.fillRect(j * (canvas.width / max), i * (canvas.height / max), canvas.width / max, canvas.height / max);
    }
  }
  circle();
  setTimeout(draw, 10);
}
draw();
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, I know it is to do with the canvas creation as when I remove it, and replace it with a static one, the problem is gone:

```js
var max = 50;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var x, y;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function circle() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
  ctx.beginPath();
  console.log(x, y);
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  x = mousePos.x;
  y = mousePos.y;
}, false);

function draw() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < max; j++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(255 - 5.5 * i) + ',' + Math.floor(255 - 5.5 * j) + ',0)';
      ctx.fillRect(j * (canvas.width / max), i * (canvas.height / max), canvas.width / max, canvas.height / max);
    }
  }
  circle();
  setTimeout(draw, 10);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the canvas's CSS style will stretch and squish the pixels. That's why your circle becomes an oval.

Instead, set the canvas element's width and height. This actually adds (or removes) pixels to the canvas to become the specified size. This will keep your circle circular. ;-)

```
canvas.width=500;    // no need to add "px"
canvas.height=400;
```

Comment: Ah, I knew the answer would be something silly! That does explain a few things... I wonder why it was stretched just in the one axis though....

Comment: @jaunt It was irregularly stretched because the native canvas width is 300 wide by 150 tall. So the pixels were proportionally stretched more vertically than horizontally. Cheers!